# Count blobs (cell nuclei) in a 3D image, vtk marching cubes

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to count cell nuclei from a 3D image I have rendered using a vtk marching cubes filter. The image here [image: attached image] is the result after processing with vtk.marchingcubes. Does vtk have any built-in features to help with counting the blobs in the image?

I am struggling to find good resources if anyone could point me in a good direction it would be much appreciated as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look at the `vtkConnectivityFilter` with option `SetExtractionModeToAllRegions()`.
You can then further assess the blobs size by their volume or surface.
This is an [example](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/examples/advanced/splitmesh.py) of how it's done in `vedo`:

[image]